# How to find gap values between variables in C code with given assembly code?

Tags: c, gcc

Given: A = 5 and B = 9, what is the gap between...

- w and x?
- y and p?
- p and z?
- z and q?

Found this answer on Chegg but I am not sure if it is correct.

> - gap between w and x = w is a character array of size 30 but x in an integer of 7+1 bits in a 32 bit processor
> - gap between y and p = y is a short array of size 6 but p is an integer
> - gap between p and z = p is an integer but z is a double array of size 6
> - gap between z and q = z is a double array of dimension 6 but q is a short variable

#### Code

```
typedef struct {
    char w[A][B];
    int x;
} str1;

typedef struct {
    short y[B];
    int p;
    double z[B];
    short q; 
} str2;

void doSub(str1 *t, str2 *u) {
    int v1 = u->p;
    int v2 = u->q;
    t->x = v1-v2;
}
```

#### Assembly code generated for doSub procedure

```
# t in %rdi, u in %rsi
doSub:
    movswl   96(%rsi), %edx
    movl     20(%rsi), %eax
    subl     %edx, %eax
    movl     %eax, 48(%rdi)
    ret
```

Comment: You are asking about structure packing rules, which are compiler dependent.  You can look this stuff up with Google.

Answer (score 1):

> w and x

`w` has size `5*9=45` but `x` needs alignment of `4` bytes so the gap is going to be `3` bytes. Can also be seen in the assembly accessing offset `48` for `x`.

> y and p

`y` has size `9*2=18` and `p` needs alignment to `4` bytes so the gap is `2`. Can also be seen in the assembly code accessing offset `20`.

> p and z

`p` has size `4`, so ends at offset `24`. `q` is at offset `96` (seen in the assembly), `z` has size `9*8=72` so `z` starts at `96-72=24`. The gap is thus `0`. (Alignment of `double` may vary, hence working backwards from the assembly code.)

> z and q

Since `q` is a short and is aligned to just `2` bytes, there is no gap after `z`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stddef.h>

printf("w to x: %lu\n", offsetof(str1, x) - offsetof(str1, w));
printf("y to p: %lu\n", offsetof(str2, p) - offsetof(str2, y));
printf("p to z: %lu\n", offsetof(str2, z) - offsetof(str2, p));
printf("z to q: %lu\n", offsetof(str2, q) - offsetof(str2, z));
```

Relying on the resulting numbers in any meaningful way is generally a bad idea.

Comment: `offsetof()` returns `size_t`; the correct format for that is `%zu` per C99 (using `z` for `size_t` rather than `l` for `long`).